# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException while implementing RIOT CMS to Spring Java web application

Tags: java, spring, content-management-system

I am trying to implement Riot CMS to my Spring-java web application using 
http://www.riotfamily.org/docs/quickstart.html

I got skeleton.zip and code using:

`wget http://riotfamily.org/setup.xml && ant -f setup.xml`

Then imported the code to implement the same in eclipse...build is successful but 404 with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Any mistake in my steps ?

[EDIT]
The error message is:

```
    Error configuring application listener of class 
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener at 
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:16‌​76)
```

Comment: for which class its throwing ClassNotFoundException?

Comment: How are you deploying you app on your server once you have built it? Are you building with Maven?

Comment: Hi Pranalee, The error message is the following=====>  Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)

Comment: Hi Traroth, I am using Ant as given in http://www.riotfamily.org/docs/quickstart.html

Comment: I am using Apache Tomcat server for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the `spring-web.jar` dependency.  This jar contains the class your application is complaining about.

Comment: Hi Tom, I have spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar & spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar already included.                                                          Markers are showing 2 errors a)Ant Buildfile problem.Premature end of file. b)Faceted Project  Problem (Target runtime Apache Tomcat v5.5 is not defined)

Comment: Well, if your buildFile is not running correctly it might be that the dependencies are not all copied.  You should fix the running of the buildfile first.  Update your question with the output so someone might help you.

Comment: Hi Tom,                                                           1)I created Java dynamic project called newRiotDemo and put setup.xml (http://www.riotfamily.org/setup.xml) in WebContent .                     2)Then ran wget http://riotfamily.org/setup.xml && ant -f setup.xml terminal                                                                      3)Then refreshed project.put index.html in Webcontent.                4) no exception in console,no markers now but not getting my desired admin page while giving http://localhost:8080/newRiotDemo/riot

Comment: while building o/p is===>ant -f build.xml
Buildfile: /home/10002/workspaceNew/newRiotDemo/WebContent/build.xml

init:

-init-local-db:

configure:
     [echo] Merging configuration. Profile: 10002

compile:
    [javac] /home/10002/workspaceNew/newRiotDemo/WebContent/build.xml:140: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

webapp:
     [copy] Copying 2 files to /home/10002/workspaceNew/newRiotDemo/WebContent/webapp/WEB-INF/classes

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds